# Dynamic variable creation for multiple AJAX calls (SharePoint Online)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I use the following code to generate jquery datatables with data returned from SharePoint Online JSON on AJAX call. As My SPO list has over 50K rows and SPO has a 5000 view threshold limit, i make multiple ajax calls with REST API multiple date range filters and concat the results. The concatenated results are then passed as data source for the datatables plugin.

Kindly assist to shorten the following code for year variables and make the same to dynamically enter date ranges to make multiple AJAX calls. I'm guessing the process is to first read current year, generate first and last dates for current year, and then create new variables in descending order till 2005.

```
var results;
var allResults = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    load();
});

function load() {
    var year2021 = $.ajax({    
        url: "SPO_Site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SPO_List')/items?$top=5000&$select=*,EncodedAbsUrl&$filter=(Date%20ge%20datetime%272020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z%27)%20and%20(Date%20le%20datetime%272021-12-31T00:00:00.000Z%27)",    
        type: "GET", dataType: "json", headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},    
        success: mySuccHandler, error: myErrHandler}); 
    var year2020 = $.ajax({    
        url: "SPO_Site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SPO_List')/items?$top=5000&$select=*,EncodedAbsUrl&$filter=(Date%20ge%20datetime%272019-12-31T00:00:00.000Z%27)%20and%20(Date%20le%20datetime%272020-12-31T00:00:00.000Z%27)",    
        type: "GET", dataType: "json", headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},    
        success: mySuccHandler, error: myErrHandler}); 
        
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    var year2005 = $.ajax({    
        url: "SPO_Site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SPO_List')/items?$top=5000&$select=*,EncodedAbsUrl&$filter=(Date%20ge%20datetime%272004-12-31T00:00:00.000Z%27)%20and%20(Date%20le%20datetime%272005-12-31T00:00:00.000Z%27)",    
        type: "GET", dataType: "json", headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},    
        success: mySuccHandler, error: myErrHandler});          
    
    function mySuccHandler(a) {
        results = a.d.results;
        if (allResults.length > 0)
            allResults = allResults.concat(results);
        else
            allResults = results;        
    }
    function myErrHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        console.log("Could not complete call: " + errorMessage);        
    };

   $.when(year2021, year2020, year2019, year2018, year2017, year2016, year2015, year2014, year2013, year2012, year2011, year2010, year2009, year2008, year2007, year2006, year2005).done(function(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17){
    $('#table_id').DataTable({
        data:allResults,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        columns: [
                    { data: "Reg" },
                    { data: "EncodedAbsUrl",
                        "render": function (data, type, full)
                        {return '<a href="'+data+'" target="_blank">View</a>';}             
                    }
        ]
    });
   });  
};
```

Comment: use recurssion its very simple

Comment: also if any year having more than 5k records then you will get error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your find yourself copy-pasting code, stop immediately and write a function and a loop.

When you find yourself copy-pasting code 15 times, you should have stopped 14 times ago to write a function and a loop.

The function:

```
function getItemsByYear(year, topRows=5000) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        url: "SPO_Site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SPO_List')/items?" + $.param({
            $top: topRows,
            $select: '*,EncodedAbsUrl',
            $filter: `(Date ge datetime'${year}-01-01T00:00:00.000Z') and (Date lt datetime'${year + 1}-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')`
        }),
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.d.results;
    })
    .fail(function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        console.log("Could not complete call: " + errorMessage);        
    });
}
```

The loop:

```
$(function () {
    let currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear(),
        requests = [];
    for (let counter = 0; counter < 15; counter++) {
        requests.push(getItemsByYear(currentYear - counter));
    }
    $.when.apply($, requests).done(function (itemsByYear) {
        $('#table_id').DataTable({
            data: itemsByYear.flat(),
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            columns: [
                { data: "Reg" },
                { data: "EncodedAbsUrl", "render": function (data, type, full)
                    {return '<a href="'+data+'" target="_blank">View</a>';}             
                }
            ]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi thankyou for the answer. Could you pls have a look at the date range in the filters? seems like the start date and end dates are the same?

Comment: @JacksonChristopher Yeah, that was an oversight.

Comment: Appreciate the assistance. Thank you.

Comment: Will mark it right away once i sort this one out. Meanwhile, the year counts down to 2007 and i am guessing that is because of the counter<15 in the loop. The script makes 15 calls (verified in Chrome XHR) but datatables only prints out data for 2021. Any suggestion?

Comment: @JacksonChristopher Well... adapt the code to your needs of course. You're not supposed to copy and paste my code. I know people come to SO to do exactly that most of the time, but it's not the point of this site. You are supposed to read it, *understand* it (that includes reading the documentation of functions you have not seen yet), and then make the necessary changes. If you ask me to change the above to count a different number of years, that would mean you've not been doing your part.

Comment: ...if the `for` loop above does not do what you had in mind, change it, or use a different loop. The point of the answer was "use a function and a loop", not "use *this* function and *this* loop".

Comment: Appreciate the patience. As i am beginner, im still trying to figure this one. Thank you.

Comment: @JacksonChristopher No worries, take your time. But the sooner you get off the "copy & paste" mentality, the better. This goes for your own code, and it goes double for code from the Internet.

Comment: Declared 2 variables as done earlier, concat the results generates froum your functions and passed it as datasource for datatables generation. Worked perfect. Answer marked as accepted. Appreciate all the support. Cheers.

Comment: ...look at it like this: The code in my answer is untested. It has to be - I don't have SharePoint, I don't know the rest of your page structure, and I don't have any idea what data the server returns. There might be bugs in there, or it might not do exactly what you need in any number of ways. Even with best intentions I can't give any guarantees. That's why it's important that you read, understand and adapt the code. The core lesson is the same, but the code itself is only an example.

Comment: @JacksonChristopher You don't need global variables for this. Global variables like your `results`and `allResults` are a code smell and explicitly unnecessary. Array concatenation is done by `itemsByYear.flat()`.